# Limits without L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate:

> $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{2h}-1}{h}$$

Now one way would be using the Maclaurin expansion for $e^{2x}$

However, can we solve it using the definition of the derivative (perhaps considering $f(x)=e^x$)? Many thanks for your help! $$$$
EDIT: I forgot to mention to please not use L'Hopital's Rule. Using it, the problem becomes trivial and loses all chances of getting a beautiful solution.

Comment: Use $f(x)=e^{2x}$. Your limit is $f'(0)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra You should definitely post that as an answer.

Comment: Sir, could you please explain how the limit is $f'(0)$? This is what I'm supposed to understand, but am as yet unable to.

Comment: $f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{ f(0+h)-f(0)\over h} =\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{e^{2(0+h)}-e^{2\cdot0}\over h} = \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{e^{2h}-e^{0}\over h}= \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}{e^{2h}-1\over h}$.

Comment: Stop copying from [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/problems/for-julian-i/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting $e^{2h}-1=(e^h-1)(e^h+1)$ and recalling a notable limit does the job.

Comment: Sir, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: after substitition, could u get 2 ?

Comment: Sir, actually, I meant to ask if there was a solution which would involve the definition of the derivative and not L'hospital's Rule

Comment: we can't use l'hopital as it's not deriveable at x=0

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{2h}-1}{h} = 2 \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{2h}-1}{h} = 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 2\cdot 1 = 2,$$ where I made the substituition $x = 2h$ just to make things easier for you to visualize. I used one of the fundamental limits along with the fact that $h \to 0 \iff x \to 0$.

Comment: Sir, actually, I meant to ask if there was a solution which would involve the definition of the derivative and not L'hospital's Rule

Comment: I didn't used L'Hospital's rule. $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$is the definition of the derivative of $e^x$ evaluated at $x = 0$. And there's a lot of ways to see this, it depends on what your definition of the exponential is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, with $f(x) = e^x$, we have $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{e^h - 1}{h} = f'(0) = 1$.

Therefore, $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{2h} - 1}{h} = \lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(e^h - 1)}{h}(e^h + 1) = 1 \cdot (1 + 1) = \boxed 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $e^{2h}-1=(e^h-1)(e^h+1)$, we get

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{2h}-1}{h} &= 2 \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{
(e^h-1)(e^h+1)}{h} \\&= \lim_{h \to 0}(e^h+1)\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} \\&= 2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} \\&=2\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{0+h}-e^0}{h} \\&=2f'(0)=2e^0=2\cdot1=2\end{align*}

with $f(x)=e^x$ of course.